# Is formatting a USB stick to NTFS a good idea?

Tags: android, ntfs, usb-drive, fat32

I have a Sandisk dual drive USB stick which can be plugged into android and PC. I was wondering if I should format it to NTFS before using. I intend to use it for storing my important files from android, which are quite large. I often find my USB sticks and microSD cards becoming corrupt and unable to be read without formatting first. So I wonder if NTFS is more reliable and restorable than FAT32 for storing my important data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not support NTFS. This is from the FAQ of Transcend (a popular SD card vendor):

> Android doesn't support NTFS file system. If the SD card or USB flash drive you insert is NTFS file system, it won't be supported by your Android device.
> Android supports FAT32/Ext3/Ext4 file system. Most of the the latest smartphones and tablets support exFAT file system.
> Usually, whether the file system is supported by a device or not depends on the devices software/hardware.

Please check the file system your device supports.

https://www.transcend-info.com/Support/FAQ-897

You might want to consider ext4 for large file sizes.

Comment: Yes but I use a third party app to read NTFS in android. I thought since NTFS is a journaling file system it is less likely to get corrupted. Also I have Widows on my PC so I guess ext4 won't be supported in that.